# Where are the JarFiles and how can I add them into Selnium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, jar, extentreports

Downloaded latest extentreport jarfiles zip folder and extracted them. I see only two folder as displayed in the image[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpjGE.png) and sub-folders contain lots of class file

I want to add the latest jarfiles to my project. Although, I could make use of Maven Project but wanted to do it manually by adding those downloaded jarfiles. Unfortunately, I could not find any jar files. There are java class files, properties file,pom file etc..but no jar files. Am I missing something or there is some way extract jars or add the META-INF folder to the project

While running the project i'm getting this error below. As I understood, its a runtime error since the class files are not available but its available during compiling

**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: freemarker/template/TemplateModelException**

Please suggest

Comment: I get the jar files from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.aventstack/extentreports

Comment: I also downloaded from the same place but after extracting the folder I don't see any jar files inside

Comment: The download is literally a jar...